# Framework7 and Ajax

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, frameworks

I wnt to use framework7 to update some iPhone/iPad apps to IOS7 look-and-feel.
Framework7 is a great set of templates but uses Ajax so does not load local pages (as will be needed for a phonegap build). The alaxLinks setting in the initialise JS causes the local page to load but not just in the sidebar (for a sidebar link) or just in the main window (for a link not in the sidebar).
An suggestions for retaining the functionality (just fill the calling frame) but with local pages?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Inline Pages (DOM Cache). See this page for documentation http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/pages-inline.html#.VLmF_cnhi2w